# Build string from product list in Ansible

Tags: ansible

My need is to install list of php extensions for many defined php versions.

Basicly I have a list with php versions and another with set of extensions :

```
php_defaults_modules:
  - curl
  - mbstring
  - gd
  - json
  - imap
  - readline
  - xml
  - zip
  - mysql
  - pgsql

php_version:
 - 7.4
 - 7.2
```

I wrote the following tasks for packet installation :

```
- name: "Install base modules"
  apt:
    name: "php{{ item[0] }}-{{ item[1] }}"
    state: present
  notify:
    - Reload FPM
  loop: "{{  php_version |product( php_defaults_modules)|list }}"
```

But it takes too much time, as the check operation is done for each packets.
That's why I would prefer generate a single line to transmit to apt. The equivalent of :

```
apt install php7.2-curl php7.2-mb [...] php7.4-mysql php 7.4-pgsql
```

I tried something like

```
- name: Define base modules
  set_fact:
    php_extensions: "{{ php_extensions }} + '[ php{{ item[0] }}-{{ item[1] }} ] '"
  loop: "{{  php_version |product( php_defaults_modules) | list }}"
```

But obviously it's not the solution.

Is there a way to make installation and checks quicker?

Thanks

Comment: `But obviously it's not the solution.` => can you please explain why ? Because **IT IS** clearly the solution. As specified explicitly in the `apt` module documentation, you should not use a loop over package names but send the list of package names directly to the `name` attribute.

Comment: I mean, building a list is the solution, but the way I did it doesn't work. It give me the following string ` "[] + '[ php7.4-curl ] ' + '[ php7.4-mbstring ] ...`

Answer (score -1):

Here is my solution, not building a list, but a string and then split it. Maybe not the best solution, but it works :

```
- name: Define base modules
  set_fact:
    php_extensions: ""

- name: Define base modules
  set_fact:
    php_extensions: "{{ php_extensions }} php{{ item[0] }}-{{ item[1] }}"
  loop: "{{ php_version |product( php_defaults_modules ) | list }}"

- name: Install php packages
  apt:
    name: "{{ php_extensions.split() }}"
  notify:
    - Reload FPM
```

Comment: `php_extensions: "{{ php_extensions | default([]) + ['php' + item.0 + '-' + item.1] }}"`. And for future questions, you should consider banning "It's not working" from your vocabulary on Q&A sites like SO, at least when used on its own. [It does not accurately describe your problem](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/)